# Rspec2 testing a before_validation method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, rspec, rspec2

I have the following to remove the spaces on a specific attribute.

```
#before_validation :strip_whitespace

protected
  def strip_whitespace
    self.title = self.title.strip
  end
```

And I want to test it. For now, I've tried:

```
it "shouldn't create a new part with title beggining with space" do
   @part = Part.new(@attr.merge(:title => " Test"))
   @part.title.should.eql?("Test")
end
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Validations won't run until the object is saved, or you invoke `valid?` manually.  Your `before_validation` callback isn't being run in your current example because your validations are never checked.  In your test I would suggest that you run `@part.valid?` before checking that the title is changed to what you expect it to be.

#### app/models/part.rb

```
class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :strip_whitespace

protected
  def strip_whitespace
    self.title = self.title.strip
  end
end
```

#### spec/models/part_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Part do
  it "should remove extra space when validated" do
    part = Part.new(:title => " Test")
    part.valid?
    part.title.should == "Test"
  end
end
```

This will pass when the validation is included, and fails when the validation is commented out.

Comment: Test is passing even I comment the `before_validation` line.

Comment: I've added code from a quick test I threw together which works as expected.  If you still have trouble there must be something in your app that is different so we might need to see more of your code to help further

Comment: It seems that `.eql?("Test")` has a different behavior from `== "Test"`. Changing this, the test works as expected. Thank you @danivovich !

Comment: Very interesting.  A close look at the rspec docs show that should.eql? isn't the expected use of checking equality, use either `==` or `eq(..)`.  I think the line you had was just evaluating that "Test" was not the same as the matcher, but not asserting anything. http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/equality-matchers

Answer (score 4):

referring to @danivovich example

```
class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :strip_whitespace

protected
  def strip_whitespace
    self.title = self.title.strip
  end
end
```

the proper way to write the spec is to separately write spec on **strip_whitespace** method and then just check if model class have callback set on it, like this:.

```
describe Part do
  let(:record){ described_class.new }

  it{ described_class._validation_callbacks.select{|cb| cb.kind.eql?(:before)}.collect(&:filter).should include(:strip_whitespace) }

  #private methods
  describe :strip_whitespace do
    subject{ record.send(:strip_whitespace)} # I'm using send() because calling private method
    before{  record.stub(:title).and_return('    foo    ')
    it "should strip white spaces" do
      subject.should eq 'foo'
      # or even shorter
      should eq 'foo'
    end
  end
end
```

if you need to skip callback behavior in some scenarios use

```
before{ Part.skip_callback(:validation, :before, :strip_whitespace)}
before{ Part.set_callback( :validation, :before, :strip_whitespace)}
```

**Update 20.01.2013**

BTW I wrote a gem with RSpec matchers to test this https://github.com/equivalent/shoulda-matchers-callbacks

In general I don't recommend callback at all. They are fine for example in this question, however once you do more complicated stuff like:

After create->

- link account to user
- create notification
- send email to Admin

...then you should create custom service object to deal with this and test them separately.

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/398-service-objects
- http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/