# Rspec and 'before_validation' callback issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, rspec

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 and RSpec 2. I know that there are some known problems on using RSpec and a `before_validation` callback, because *the `before_validation` seems not to be triggered* when run in spec files. You can find a lot of similar issues (for example, by doing a [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=ror%20%22validates_inclusion_of%22%20lambda&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3aofficial&source=hp&q=rspec%20%22before_validation%22&pbx=1&oq=rspec%20%22before_validation%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=s&gs_upl=119379l120525l3l123532l4l4l3l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=23ce9c3efefc512c&biw=1024&bih=1194)).

I am wondering if, at this time, **anyone has come up with a solution to this problem?**

*P.S.*: I have read that some people have proposed to use mocks, others people to switch from a `before_validation` to some other callback (eg: to a `before_save`) or to use the `save(:validate => false)` method (so to skip validations)... and so on... but no one seems to have solved the "real" problem. *What do you think should be done in such cases in order to solve the issue?*

Comment: There's no reason for `before_validation` not to be triggered in tests -- model tests don't do anything special during setup. I honestly think people don't know how to write these sorts of tests. Do you have a test you're trying to get passed?

Comment: +1 for an example of what is not working. Give us a simple model with a before_validation check, and the spec you're writing to validate that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361036/rspec2-testing-a-before-validation-method

Did you call .valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can't get around using mocks, try reloading your instance using the reload method and after that your test.